# Is it possible to post to a YouTube Feed via API?

Tags: youtube-api, feed

I would like to post to the youtube feed via API.

The feed is a relatively unknown place where uploads, likes, comments, etc are shared automatically (dependent on privacy settings)

Image of the feed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7akLd.png

Via Youtube.com you can also manually post to the feed via the text post with the filler text "Create a post". Videos and playlists can be attached - either your own or any uploaded video as seen in the image.

I believe an element of the feed might be called a "bulletin message" because when I inspect element in chrome "post-bulletin-message" is the name of the element.

Searching thru the API documentation as well as online only reveled this unspecific /unanswered question from 2010: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/4VYyMNsFdfk

Ideally:
* Post to feed
* hide/delete from feed

Needed attributes:
* text (optional)
* specify the optional video/playlist

There currently are API calls in the documentation to read the feed but not to post to it as far as I can determine.

Thanks in advance, any pointers are appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post a "channel bulletin" using version 3 of the Data API, via a [youtube.activities.insert()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/insert) call.

There's sample code in Java, Python, and Ruby linked to off of that page.